# How to use JS script with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scripting

I have the following problem.

I am using **React**. I am making a website and I would like it to work as a slideshow, that is, a component with a greeting is displayed and after a few seconds it disappears and the rest of the page appears with navigation, showcase, etc. There is only one problem. In the showcase, I use a script with particles that constantly move around the screen (the script is in vanilla JS). I have no idea **how to make it so that I can use this script in react, so that it only works in the showcase component**, because currently it only works when the page is refreshed, and it doesn't load immediately when you go from the first component to the showcase.

This is what I've found but I don't understand it and it doesn't work for me:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import useScript from './UseScript';

const Showcase = props => {
  useScript('./particles.js');

  // rest of your component
    return (
    <div class="container">
        <h1><p>Learn more</p></h1>
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Showcase
```